# correctly declare pointers, allocate memory, and send them as parameters c++

Tags: c++

How correctly declare pointers, allocate memory, and send them as parameters in fuctions to write values ? The code below is what I tried but it doesn't work correctly. I need the same logic. I mean declare, set, then show.

```
...

struct complex {
  int i;
  int r;
};

void set(complex *n, int i, int r){
  n = new complex;
  n->i = i;
  n->r = r;
}

void show(complex *n){
  std::cout << n->i << " " << n->r;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  complex *n;
  set(n,10,20);
  show(n);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to pass the pointer by reference in your set function.

Comment: OT: Don't forget `delete n;`.

Comment: You really don't want to be doing that. You don't need dynamic allocation at all here. Just `complex n{10, 20};`.

Comment: ok, but if i need dynamic allocation, how to accomplish this

Comment: I would have `set` return a (smart) pointer. And change its name to something else.

Comment: and... stop. c++ works much better if you pass by value.

Comment: @student: **By far** the easiest way to use dynamic allocation is via a class that wraps it. E.g. `std::string` uses dynamic allocation internally because it can't know how long your string will become, but on the outside you don't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your function set couldn't work, because by doing

```
n = new complex;
```

whatever the pointer you pass to the function, the pointer will be overwritten by the pointer on the new object.

- You can pass the pointer via reference (on C++ only...) like that

  `void set(complex* &n, int i, int r)`

  And by doing so you'll modify the value of the original pointer.
- You can also simply return the pointer by a `return n`
  But obviously if the prototype of your function must stay like that, it's not possible...
- Or, **but it's highly discouraged**, as many said, you can use a double pointer, and it's quite tricky !
  If I don't make mistake, you create a

  `complex** n`

  You pass it to your function

  `set(complex** n, int i, int r)`

  And then you load

  `*n = new complex`

  And it must work if you pass `*n` to all your function instead of n...

And **don't forget to delete your object at the end** ;)

Comment: Thank you, you are correct, but if I use complex**, then how do I set the values of that double pointer n->i wont work

Comment: Because you have to replace all the occurrence of your current `n` with `*n` : your pointer n doesn't point anymore on your structure directly, but on a pointer on your structure !
So for instance, use `(*n)->i = 1` to modify your object

Comment: @student: Please don't take the advice to use `complex**`. C++ rarely requires pointers, and pointers to pointers are truly rare. The first part of this answer suggests to use a reference, and that indeed is the better solution. But as juanchopanza already noted in a comment, just avoid the dynamic memory outright.

Comment: Indeed, double pointer is a pretty unclear solution. By the way, `struct` usage in C++ is not very appropriate too, even if it's sometime easier

Comment: @DamienGallet `struct` is fine. It is the same s `class`, except it involves less typing most of the time.

Comment: `complex** n` is a terrible idea, IMO it would be better for the answer to not mention it at all. In C++ you can actually pass by reference as part of the language. You don't need to do the hack of implementing pass-by-reference by doing pass-by-pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the initialization part from **set** function and put it in the **main** function.

see this link for explanation.

[Why can I not initialize an array by passing a pointer to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260510/why-can-i-not-initialize-an-array-by-passing-a-pointer-to-a-function)

Check this code

```
 //#include<windows.h>
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  struct complex {
    int i;
    int r;
  };

  void set(complex *n, int i, int r) {
    // n = new complex;   
    n->i = i;
    n->r = r;
  }

  void show(complex *n) {
    std::cout << n->i << " " << n->r;
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    complex *n = new complex();
    set(n, 10, 20);
    show(n);
    delete n;
    //system("pause"); TRY TO AVOID THIS. MAKES YOUR CODE LESS PORTABLE.
    return 0;
  }
```

see this link.

[c++ - system("pause"); - Why is it wrong? - Stack Overflow](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong&ved=0ahUKEwjBmtuTpoHPAhWMr48KHfKMC8AQFggkMAE&usg=AFQjCNGudkwx9OS7jD2neR6LvnUbZu42pg&sig2=iLki5mN0a32bsJLjC3lJww)